# Android: It is possible to load an activity as a view?

Tags: android

For example like,

View v = MapActivity.class;

below works as an activity but it doesnt work when i try to build the view with an adapter.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.zoommain);

mZoomControl = new DynamicZoomControl();

mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image800x600);

mZoomListener = new LongPressZoomListener(getApplicationContext());
mZoomListener.setZoomControl(mZoomControl);

//not working... loading custom view
mZoomView = (ImageZoomView)findViewById(R.id.zoomview);
//mZoomView = (ImageZoomView)context.getResources().findViewById(R.id.zoomview);
//context.getResources()
mZoomView.setZoomState(mZoomControl.getZoomState());
mZoomView.setImage(mBitmap);
mZoomView.setOnTouchListener(mZoomListener);

mZoomControl.setAspectQuotient(mZoomView.getAspectQuotient());

resetZoomState();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
```

`View` is not part of the hierarchy. `View v = MapActivity.class;` doesn't make much sense.

What you can do, if View is part of an Activity in the same app, is:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.zoommain);
```

Assuming that you gave an id `zoomain` to your main layout.

Alternatively, you can create your own custom layout, implementing the custom `Listener`, and then reuse it in more than one `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is the explanation i was needing.